# scheme : delay and force for interactive I/O

Tags: scheme

First I'll give question.

Suppose define input to be a function that returns an "istream" - a promise that when forced will yield a pair, the cdr of which is an istream:

```
(define input (lambda () (delay (cons (read) (input)))))
```

now we can define the driver to expect an "ostream" - an empty list or a pair, the cdr of which is an ostream :

```
(define driver
  (lambda (s)
    (if (null? s) '()
      (begin
      (display (car s))
      (driver (force (cdr s)))))))
```

note that use of force.

show how to write the function squares so that it takes an istream as argument and returns an ostream. you should then be able to type (driver (squares (input))) and see appropriate behavior.

and squares in book is above.

```
(define squares (lambda (a)
  (cons "please enter a number\n"
    (let ((n (car a)))
      (if (eof-object? n) '()
        (cons (* n n) (cons #\newline (squares (cdr a)))))))))

(define output (squares (input)))
```

I don't have any idea how to solve it and where i can start this. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the solution.  (NOTE: the force is done as part of the driver function). The important thing to understand is that the "stream" functions (input, squares) return a delayed expression which is a pair of 2 items of which 2nd is another delayed expression and so on, also the `force` function works on normal values too hence the last part in `squares` return 3 cons items.

```
(define input (lambda () (delay (cons (read) (input)))))

(define driver
  (lambda (s)
     (let ((s (force s)))
       (if (null? s) '()
           (begin
            (display (car s))
            (flush-output)
            (driver (force (cdr s))))))))


(define squares
  (lambda (a)
     (delay (cons "please enter a number\n"
              (delay (let ((nums (force a)))
                       (if (null? (car nums)) '()
                           (cons (* (car nums)
                                    (car nums))
                                 (cons #\newline (squares (cdr nums)))))))))))
```

Now you can run it like : `(driver (squares (input)))`. To exit the prompt user will need to type empty list `()`